# How to build Perl with PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT?

Tags: perl

According to [perlguts](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html):

> When Perl is built with PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT, extensions that call
>   any functions in the Perl API will need to pass the initial context
>   argument somehow. The kicker is that you will need to write it in such
>   a way that the extension still compiles when Perl hasn't been built
>   with PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT enabled.

How can I build Perl with `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`? And how can I later check if an installed Perl has been compiled with `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`?

Comment: `Perl -V` will show you the compile time options, amongst other things. look to see if PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT is listed

Comment: @JGNI `perl -V | grep -P '(?i:IMPLICIT)'` gives no output. Still, how can I be sure if this means my Perl has not been built with `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` or if the build option is simply not picked up by `perl -V`?

Comment: To build Perl with `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`, maybe `./Configure -Accflags="-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT" && make`?

Comment: And then, `perl -V | grep IMPLICIT` shows that Perl was compiled with `-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`.

Comment: @Dada Thanks, I will test it now

Comment: FYI, how I found that: I went to Perl5 sources and greped `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`, which appeared to be a cpp macro (since there are some `#ifdef PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`). I then googled `perl set build options`. Second result was `https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/INSTALL`, and I saw `-Accflags=-D...` there. `-D` defines a cpp macro, `ccflags` sounds like a reasonable name for c flags, so this seemed like a good option. Then I tested it.

Comment: @Dada I tried now: `perlbrew install perl-5.29.0 --as=5.29.0ic --Accflags="-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT"; perlbrew switch 5.29.0ic; perl -V | grep IMPLICIT` and it still gives no output..

Comment: @Dada Ok, found the mistake: The `A` option to `perlbrew` should be passed with a single dash (not double) `-Accflags="-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT"` and it works fine now!

Comment: @HåkonHægland Feel free to write an answer ;) (I won't)

Comment: `. Configure ... -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` isn't sufficient?

Comment: Normally you don't define `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` manually, you just build your perl with or without thread support. A perl without thread support won't pass a context argument, a perl with thread support will use an initial context argument. If your extension builds with both threaded and unthreaded perls, it handles contexts correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by @Dada, there is information in the [Build and Installation guide for perl 5](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.28.0/INSTALL) on how to build Perl with `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT`. The `-A` option is used with the `Configure` script to add
 `-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` to  `ccflags`. For example, to build 5.28.0 with `PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT` and install in `$HOME/localperl`:

```
 wget https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.28.0.tar.gz
 tar -xzf perl-5.28.0.tar.gz
 cd perl-5.28.0
 ./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl -Accflags="-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT"
 make
 make test
 make install
```

alternatively you can use `perlbrew`:

```
perlbrew install perl-5.28.0 --as=5.28.0ic -Accflags="-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT"
perlbrew switch 5.28.0ic
```

The second part of the question: How to check if an installed Perl has been compiled with PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT? As noted by @JGNI, `perl -V` can be used:

```
$ perl -V | grep PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
    config_args='-de -Dprefix=/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/5.28.0ic -Dusedevel -Accflags=-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -Aeval:scriptdir=/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/5.28.0ic/bin'
    ccflags ='-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
    cppflags='-DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include'
    PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
```

Alternatively, you can access the Perl configuration information using the [Config](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config) module.